# MS Edge browser fails to render JS 'onmousedown' and 'onclick' at same time

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html-select, microsoft-edge

Within JavaScript, `onmousedown` when combined with `onclick` corrupts the `onclick` event in Microsoft Edge.

The `onmousedown` event executes prior to `onclick` and works as expected in Firefox, Chrome, and even IE11.

**Question:**
Why doesn't this simple [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/sayw5190/1epwphqj/4/) render correctly in Microsoft Edge?

The ability to change an HTML 'Select' via the mouse is lost. The user can still change the option using arrow keys, and there are no error messages being written to the console log.

Similar posts suggested adding `.focus()` yet even this design failed in rectifying this specific problem.

```
document.getElementById("lyrList").onclick = function(){
    var selectedField = document.getElementById("lyrList");
    selectedField.options[selectedField.selectedIndex].style.color = "red";
} 

document.getElementById("lyrList").onmousedown= function(){
    var selectedField = document.getElementById("lyrList");
    selectedField.options[selectedField.selectedIndex].style.color = "blue";
}
```

**EDIT UPDATE:**

There were two bugs;

1st: changing `onclick` to `onchange` allowed the select to open within Edge.

2nd. dynamically setting the color via JS (`.style.color`) or jQuery (`.options.item(i)).css('color', 'red'`); prevents the user from changing the value of the select box. (Microsoft is aware of this bug)

Event listeners were attempted as a means to unsuccessfully get around this bug.
updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1epwphqj/20/) for posterity.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fails to render" and "corrupts"? What happens instead?

Comment: it is impossible to change the selection

Comment: So this only happens if you use both event handlers, and they still are both executed fine? And even the `selectedIndex` changes as expected, but it doesn't render the selected option any more? Does it happen if you use `addEventListener` as well?

Comment: @Bergi, oops, made a typo in the previous js fiddle for listeners. The onclick & onmousedown problem persists.  [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sayw5190/1epwphqj/7/)

Comment: You don't need both handlers to reproduce.  The click handler is enough to show the issue.  I recall most browsers have had issues related to click and select in the past.  I think if you use **onchange** rather than **onclick** you can get what you are after.

Comment: @JonSG, the onchange event fixed the issue with the select options not being displayed in Edge, however there is still a conflict with 'onchange' and 'onmousedown'. As soon as 'onmousedown' is commented out it is possible to change values, but as long as 'onmousedown' is present they can't be changed. Updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sayw5190/1epwphqj/9/)

Comment: oddly enough, this seems to work **selectedField.options[selectedField.selectedIndex].style.cssText = "color: blue";**

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help and suggestions! Edge is seeing the "onmousedown" event, yet even when using an 'mousedown' listener and 'onchange', the ability to change options within an HTML select isn't possible.  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sayw5190/1epwphqj/12/) (comment out alert to see normal functionality)

Comment: I'm an engineer on the Microsoft Edge team, and see the disparity to which you are referring. I'm going to file a bug here in a moment on the issue of `style.color` preventing a select from expanding.

Comment: @Sampson, Does Microsoft have link to track the progress of this bug? or can estimated time frame be provided for when this bug may be fixed?  Although it was a long shot, tried using jQuery and it too behaved the same way within Edge.

Comment: @Tom_s You can file and track bugs publicly over at http://bugs.microsoftedge.com. I happened to have filed directly into our backend. Unfortunately, I can not offer any timeframe at this time. If you wouldn't mind, can you describe the behavior you'd like to achieve (perhaps as a list of steps/states)? I suspect we can come up with a better approach.

Comment: @Sampson, Took a look at the bug tracker and was unable to locate this bug. What title was assigned to it?

re better approach: I'm creating an interactive webmap using ESRI's GIS JS api, as the user zooms in on the the dynamic map, the js pulls the users map zoom extent. On '<select>' mousedown the map layers within '<select>' are disable/enabled if they are present at that zoom extent, '<select>' 'onchange' the drawn graphic represented by previous queried features is cleared, and prepped for next graphic js query. Could set font color in .css class but still needs tobe dynamically changed

Comment: @sampson, using CSS classes to change font colors, with each map zoom extent having a different CSS class will/should work. I wrote an AI to auto generate ~800 lines of CSS for each webmap...if this is a bug Microsoft plans to fix in the next few months i wont worry about creating a workaround, if it will be longer then i'll need to do some heavy redesigning.

Comment: @Tom_s *"Took a look at the bug tracker and was unable to locate this bug."* I submitted directly into our backend; so the item is not publicly searchable.